# Make notes in Visual Studio, but not in source code

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a tool that will let me add/attach/associate notes to lines of code in Visual Studio 2013, but does not go into the source code.

Think of post-it notes sitting on some papers I'm working on, helping me keep track of some things I need to do, when I'm done I take them off.

Comment: If the notes aren't very long, use bookmarks and edit their labels. A much better options is pinned watch windows aka datatips (possibly in combination with breakpoints) since you can add arbitrary comments there, but that of course works when debugging. But mentioning it anyway because this is imo an underestimated feature (and maybe it's what you're after, you don't state specifically if it's for debugging or not) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea46xwzd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the Visual Studio Task List
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txtwdysk.aspx

You can add items to it as needed, or add special comments in your code such as

```
// TODO: Do this later
```

Which will also show up in the task list.

Comment: It's not possible to add items as needed. It seems to only automatically add items when it detects comments such as TODO in the code.

Answer (score 4):

What I usually do, if I don't want anything in the source code, is add a textfile to my project. You can do this by clicking:

> Project -> Add New Item

And select **Text File** under `General`.

This way your notes are attached to your project to keep it central, but there is nothing actually in your source code. Maybe it helps.